# Creating Maintenance Pages for Dynamo DB tables using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

What are your suggestions for how I should creating maintenance/administration pages that allow me to add/modify/report on entries in my DynamoDB tables on AWS?

What I would like to do is to create web pages that are hosted in AWS S3 but allow me to script Dynamo DB access.

I'm trying to avoid setting up something like a LAMP stack on another host.

Answer (score 1):

Without any backend code... JavaScript (or a derivative). Try the AWS SDK for JavaScript. Or, you can use API Gateway, Lambda and JavaScript. Either work with S3-only hosting. Lambda could hide some implementation details behind an API and you don’t need to worry about managing servers. More moving parts is the trade-off.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking up that solution now